# parsing variables to a construct in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

Can someone tell me if theres a way to parse variables to the class construct when i'm loading a model in codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the manual and [sourcecode](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php) and I can tell you: no, you can not.    The code for the modelloader is as follows:

```
/**
 * Model Loader
 *
 * This function lets users load and instantiate models.
 *
 * @param   string  the name of the class
 * @param   string  name for the model
 * @param   bool    database connection
 * @return  void
 */
public function model($model, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE)
{...}
```

You could add an init-method with parameters to your model and call that after loading your model.